# Comparing attributes of two different models inside a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to compare `@question.id` with value in a database table `Work`. How can I do that inside the show action of the question controller?

I want to compare `@question.id` with `@community.community_activity`, but when I do that inside the question controller the `@community` is `nil`:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.community_activity
```

How to tackle this???

```
if @question.id != @community.community_activity.for_communities(60).object_id and current_user.role.title.strip == "Test" 
  redirect_to 'public/access_denied.html'
  return
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by 'explicitly'? Are you try to find a record in `Work` where some column equals the value of `@question.id`? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Mischa Please see the edited qustion and help me!!

Comment: To answer your question you have to show us your code. This is not enough. At least post the controller action where this is happening.

Comment: Maybe the code in question would help. Lol beaten to it.

Comment: Please show the code from all affected models.

Comment: friend unable to identify your problem.Could you please show me some code from your controller?

Comment: `@community` is `nil`. Where do you define `@community`?????????

Comment: Mithun I mean the ruby code in app/models such as question.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are showing us, all I can suggest is the following:

```
if @community.nil? || (@question.id != @community.community_activity.for_communities(60).id && current_user.role.title.strip == "Test")
  redirect_to '/access_denied.html'
  return
end
```

Or maybe this is more appropriate:

```
if (@community.nil? || @question.id != @community.community_activity.for_communities(60).id) && current_user.role.title.strip == "Test"
  redirect_to '/access_denied.html'
  return
end
```

Comment: defined the model @community_activities = CommunityActivity.for_communities(60) where for_communities is a named_scope and then it worked!! Thanks @Mischa!!!